# return multiple value from one method

Tags: java

I have a class UserFunction and it have two method getAudioFunction and getPromptFunction with returning String value, my problem is that i want to return both value in one method
 how can i able to do that

UserFunction.java

```
 public class UserFunction{ 

        Map<String,PromptBean> promptObject=new HashMap<String,PromptBean>(); 
        Map<String,AudioBean> audioObject = new HashMap<String,AudioBean>();

        XmlReaderPrompt xrpObject=new XmlReaderPrompt();
        public String getAudioFunction(String audioTag,String langMode )
        {       
            Map<String, AudioBean> audioObject=xrpObject.load_audio(langMode);          
            AudioBean audioBean=(AudioBean)audioObject.get(audioTag);           
            String av=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(audioBean.getAudio());            
            return av;
        }
        public String getPromptFunction(String promptTag,String langMode )
        {           
            Map<String, PromptBean> promptObject=xrpObject.load(langMode);
            PromptBean promptBean= (PromptBean)promptObject.get(promptTag);             
            String pv=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(promptBean.getPrompt());          
            return pv;
        }

    }
```

Comment: return custom class object instead of string

Answer (score 4):

You need to return an object which holds both values. You could create a class for this purpose. The class can have two getter methods for retrieving the values.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to return more than one value from a method in java. You can set multiple value into `Map` or `List` or create a custom class and can return that object.

```
public Map<String,String> getAudioAndPromptFunction(String audioTag,String langMode )
        {       
            Map<String,String> map =new HashMap();
            ...
            map.put("audioBean",StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(audioBean.getAudio()));
            map.put("promptBean",StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(promptBean.getPrompt());
            return map;
        }
```

or you can create a custom bean class like.

```
public class AudioPrompt{
     private String  audioBean;
     private String  promptBean;
     ...
}

public AudioPrompt getAudioAndPromptFunction(String audioTag,String langMode )
{       
     AudioPrompt audioPrompt =new AudioPrompt();
     ...
     audioPrompt.set(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(audioBean.getAudio()));
     audioPrompt.set(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(promptBean.getPrompt());
     return audioPrompt ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to return an object that includes both of the values.  This could be an array with two elements, a `Pair<A,B>` class (which holds two generic values, typically from some pan-project utility library), or a method-specific class such as:

```
public class UserFunctionXmlPairing {
    public final String audioBeanXml;
    public final String promptBeanXml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all the values you wish into a single object and return that:

```
public class Prompts {
    private Map<String, Object> prompts = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void addPrompt(String name, Object prompt) { 
        this.prompts.put(name, prompt);
    }

    public Object getPrompt(String name) { 
        this.prompts.get(name);
    }
}
```

It's even easier if your `AudioBean` and `PromptBean` have a common super class or interface.

My preference would be to lose the "Bean" in your class names.  `AudioPrompt` and `TextPrompt` would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class that holds your two strings and return that.

```
class AudioPromptPair {
    private String audio;
    private String prompt;
    public AudioPromptPair(String audio, String prompt) {
        this.audio = audio;
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    // add getters and setters
}
```